# Pandas read_html how to drop Index?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling on removing the index column from the dataframe.

Usually when I read a csv file, I can set the index = False or `index_col = 0`, and that removes the index column. But I can't do that when reading html for some reason. Any ideas? I've also tried `reset_index(drop=True)`. I don't want to set any of the columns to an index.

```
path = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M' 

canada = pd.read_html(path)    

cn_table=canada[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC , you want the 1st row as headers, Use `header=0`:

```
canada = pd.read_html(r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M',header =0, flavor = 'bs4')
```

Or:

```
canada = pd.read_html(r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M',header =0)

cn_table=canada[0]
>>cn_table

    Postcode    Borough          Neighbourhood
0   M1A         Not assigned     Not assigned
1   M2A         Not assigned     Not assigned
2   M3A         North York       Parkwoods
3   M4A         North York       Victoria Village
4   M5A         Downtown Toronto Harbourfront
5   M5A         Downtown Toronto Regent Park

... ... ... ...
288 M9Z         Not assigned     Not assigned
```

To save the dataframe to csv without index use:

```
cn_table.to_csv('path+filename.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: The output still contains an index column.

Comment: @user10939484 can you share your expected output plz?

Comment: @user10939484 did you mean `print(cn_table.to_string(index=False))` ??

Comment: No, I'd like to permanently modify the dataframe to output only the 3 columns without the index to the left. Same as your output without the index.

Comment: @user10939484 : to save the dataframe to a file without the index, use `cn_table.to_csv('path+filename.csv',index=False)` check edit at the bottom.

Comment: I'm not trying to save the dataframe just yet. I still have a lot of work to do. I just need to clean it up a bit.

Comment: @user10939484 : so why is the index bothering you?

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that. Not bothering me. The assignment I'm working on has a finished dataframe image that does not have an index so it's been annoying me, making me think I was just missing something obvious.